# I want to split a merged field delimited by tab using awk for window?

Tags: awk

the fields in column 5 and 17 were merged together and i want to split the merged ones and put in separate fields.
my data looks like this

```
326502010-12-10       320100807
368902010-12-14       420100716
```

But i want to see like this

```
32650       2010-12-10    3   20100807
36890       2010-12-14    4   20100716
```

Comment: column 5 and 17? you probably mean character 5 and 17.

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk`,

```
$ awk -vOFS="\t" '{sub(/.{5}/, "&\t", $1); sub(/./, "&\t", $2)}1' file
32650   2010-12-10  3   20100807
36890   2010-12-14  4   20100716
```

---

- `sub(/.{5}/, "&\t", $1)` Substitutes the first 5 characters with itself followed by `\t` on the first field.
- `sub(/./, "&\t", $2)}` Substitutes for the second field.
- `1` This evaluates to true always, `awk` prints the input line as default action.

Comment: Hi the script works nicely but to some of my  fields are distorted. How can i avoid distorted field after splitting the field? is it possible to fix  the field? thanks

Answer (score 1):

In case the length of the number preceeding the date varies, use this:

```
$ awk '{sub(/....-..-../,"\t&",$1); sub(/^./,"&\t",$2)} 1' file
32650   2010-12-10 3    20100807
36890   2010-12-14 4    20100716
```

`sub` replaces the date part with a tab (`\t`) and the matching part (`&`) ie. the date. About the same with the latter part for `$2`.

Answer (score 0):

Better use `sed` to split by characters:

```
$ sed -r 's/^(.{5})(.{18})/\1\t\2\t/' file
32650   2010-12-10       3  20100807
36890   2010-12-14       4  20100716
```

This captures the given characters and prints them back with a tab in between them.

Comment: But I'm using awk. I look forward to get a solution using awk

Comment: then start by posting your attempts. Also, this sed code is easily translatable into awk.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `cut` for this:

```
$ cut --output-delimiter=$'\t' -c 1-5,6-17,18- file
32650   2010-12-10      3   20100807
36890   2010-12-14      4   20100716
```

With `-c` option you can set a list representing the part of the line you want to cut. The comma `,` is replaced by the `--output-delimiter` which is set as a tab.